# Como mostrar uma lista de valores de um cadastro aplicando filtros nos valores numéricos?

Tags: python

Tenho que mostrar cadastro todo com filtro em campo numérico, tenho que escolher qual campo numérico, definir limite inferior e superior ex.: mostrar todas peças com preço >= a 45.50 e preço <= a 90.00

Tenho uma lista de lista conforme conforme código:

```
cadastroPeca = [] 
item = []

def mostrarCadastro():
  print("Cadastro atualizado:\n")
  print(cadastroPeca)
  print("")

def mostrarCadastro2(lista, filtro1, filtro2):
  for i in range(len(lista)):
    if i == filtro1 and i == filtro2:
      if i >= filtro1 or i <= filtro2:
        print(lista)
      else:
        print("Não possue!")

print("\nFiltro de Pesquisa")
    print("1- Código")
    print("2- Preço")
    print("3- Quantidade")
    print("")

    mostrarCadastro()

    campoEscolhido = input("Escolha o campo que dejesa pesquisar digitando pelo número: ")

    if campoEscolhido != "1" and campoEscolhido != "2" and campoEscolhido != "3":
      print("\nOpção digitada não existe na lista acima! Por favor, escolha uma das opções abaixo.\n")

    campoEscolhido1 = int(campoEscolhido)

    if campoEscolhido2 == 1:
      print("Opção selecionada: ", campoEscolhido2)
      filtroMenor = int(input("Informe o menor valor do item de pesquisa: "))
      filtroMaior = int(input("Informe o maior valor do item de pesquisa: "))
```

Queria saber o que pode ter faltado em minha função para retornar os valores entre duas variáveis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Quando você compara o `i`, você está comparando o index da lista, e não os valores. Para compara os valores, use `lista[i]`;

2) A sua função tem um `print(lista)` dentro do `for`, ou seja, para cada iteração do for, ele vai printar algo;

3) `if i == filtro1 and i == filtro2:` essa linha não fez nenhum sentido;

4) `if i >= filtro1 or i <= filtro2:` aqui não é `or`, é um `and`, além de ser `lista[i]`, e não `i`;

5) Recomendo usar list comprehension.

Arrumando a sua função:

```
def mostrarCadastro2(lista, filtro1, filtro2):
    lista_filtrada = []
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if lista[i] >= filtro1 and lista[i] <= filtro2:
            lista_filtrada.append(lista[i])
    return lista_filtrada #ou print(lista_filtrada)
```

Outros jeitos de fazer:

```
def mostrarCadastro2(lista, filtro1, filtro2):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x >= filtro1 and x <= filtro2 , lista))

#Ou ainda

def mostrarCadastro2(lista, filtro1, filtro2):
    return [ num for num in lista if (num >= filtro1 and num <= filtro2) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

No caso eu tenho uma lista de lista conforme trecho:

cadastroPeca = [] 
item = []

campoEscolhido = input("Escolha o campo que dejesa pesquisar digitando pelo número: ")

```
  if campoEscolhido != "1" and campoEscolhido != "2" and campoEscolhido != "3":
    print("\nOpção digitada não existe na lista acima! Por favor, escolha uma das opções abaixo.\n")

  else:
    campoEscolhido1 = int(campoEscolhido)

    if campoEscolhido1 == 1:
      print("Opção selecionada: ", campoEscolhido1)
      filtroMenor = int(input("Informe o menor valor do item de pesquisa: "))
      filtroMaior = int(input("Informe o maior valor do item de pesquisa: "))


mostrarCadastro2(cadastroPeca, filtroMenor, filtroMaior)
```

Esta me apresentando esse erro: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 120, in 
  File "python", line 27, in mostrarCadastro2
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'